# Search Results not showing up for a site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search

I have configured Search Service Application and result sources and Query transform: {searchTerms} `path:http://url:port`, and managed properties in my SP 2013 web application.Created a  search center sub site under my site collection. Given the full control for the crawling account.Went to the search results web part and selected the item from the result sources dropdown which is created at SSA level.I performed full crawl,and I checked the crawl logs and the documents was successfully crawled  but still my search results are not showing up.

Any extra settings or configurations I need to do ?

Comment: Did you get any results when you tried that query while creating the result source? I think you don't need to use port. You could try to add it like Path:http://url/* to see if you get any results.

Comment: @user19952, No, i didn't get any results when creating the result resource

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the query in the result source. Have you tried without the port? http://url

Comment: As per my requirement I need to limit the search results from a single site collection.I have 40+ site collections in my web application with different set of people having different access levels.So whoever searching for a document docA within a sitecollection1's document library should be displayed and the search results should not come from other site collections.

Comment: Did you added Start Addresses in Manage Content Sources? In Local SharePoint sites Content Source add http://<url> and sps3://<url>for people

Comment: @eVT, Yes I have already added the URLs in the content source.

Comment: @user199 , here is my query text :      {searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem) path:http://srvr1:123/sites/mysitecoll1.Are you saying that,                                                                                                  i need to enter    {searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem) path:http://url*

Answer (score 1):

Edit your result source.

Try with this query `{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem) path:"http://srvr1:123/sites/mysitecoll1"`

You need to put `http://` or `https://` in query and you should get some results in Search Result Preview window when click Test Query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who needs to see this, but I sure did ... after days of pulling out my hair - turns out owning a site and being global admin doesn't give you permission to search for a site! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-results-dont-appear-for-group-owners